# How can i find index of fully visible (complete visible) cell in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to find complete visible cell index from my `UITableView`.
Here I have attached image.

[image]

In this image number 1 and number 12 are not fully visible so it should not return index of that cell. I want only fully visible cells index that are 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `[tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]` on every cell of the array result of `[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]` and see if their frames are completely inside your view bounds. and while you are at it, make it a category for your future use.

Something like this:

```
-(NSArray *)visibleIndexPathIncludingPartials:(BOOL)includePartials
{


    NSArray *result = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];

    if(includePartials){
        return result;
    }

    NSMutableArray *mutableResult = [NSMutableArray array];


    for(NSIndexPath *indexPath in result){
        CGRect cellRect = [self.tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        if(!CGRectIsEmpty(cellRect)){

            CGRect rectInTableView = [self.tableView convertRect:cellRect toView:self.tableView.superview];

            if(rectInTableView.origin.y < 0.0){//Checks if it is beyond actual view bounds
                continue;
            }

            if(self.navigationController && !self.navigationController.navigationBar.isHidden){//in case navigation bar exists and you're expanding under top bar

                if(rectInTableView.origin.y < CGRectGetMaxY(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame)){
                    continue;
                }

            }
            if(CGRectGetMaxY(rectInTableView) > CGRectGetMaxY(self.tableView.superview.bounds)){
                continue;
            }

            //If you have bottom view like toolbars, yo should weed them out just like this

        } else { // If the index path is invalid, this might happen
            continue;
        }
        [mutableResult addObject:indexPath];
    }

    result = mutableResult;
    return result;


}
```

Answer (score 8):

you can use `indexPathsForVisibleRows` to get all visiblerows then get cellRect using `rectForRowAtIndexPath` and check if cell contains in tableview's bound.

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (NSIndexPath *indexVisible in tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows) {
    CGRect cellRect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexVisible];
    BOOL isVisible = CGRectContainsRect(tableView.bounds, cellRect);
    if (isVisible) {
        //you can also add rows if you dont want full indexPath.
        //[arr addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexVisible.row]]; 
        [arr addObject:indexVisible];
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@",arr);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: it fails to account for transparent bars.

Comment: could you please tell me where i have to add this code snippet in my code to get the visible cell?

Answer (score 2):

***Swift 5 Solution***
convert @chintan's Solution

add this code snippet to your willDisplay cell or cellForRow method

```
for indexVisible in tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows ?? [] {
    let cellRect = tableView.rectForRow(at: indexVisible)
    let isVisible = tableView.bounds.contains(cellRect)
    if isVisible {
        //you can also add rows if you dont want full indexPath.
        //[arr addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexVisible.row]]; 
        print(indexVisible)
    }
}
```